# Which method is to be applied and when?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following problem:

> 1. In how many ways 10 different balls can be put in 2 different boxes?

I solved this question like this:

1. Consider two boxes($B_1$ and $B_2$). $B_1$ can be filled in 10 ways while $B_2$ can be filled in 9 ways. So, total number of cases is $10×9 = 90$. **But** solution was something different.

> For each ball there are two options either to go in $B_1$ or $B_2$. So, total number of ways = $2×2×2...10$times = $2^{10}$

My Method does not fail in all problems.
When should I chose which method and why?

Comment: You need to understand the types of objects these each count.  Your $10\times 9$ calculation counts the number of ways of picking *exactly one* ball to go into box one while also picking *exactly one* ball to go into box two leaving the remaining eight balls unused.  The $2^{10}$ calculation corresponds to putting *all ten balls* into either box, possibly all, some, or none of the balls into box 1 while the remaining all some or none balls go into box 2.

Comment: You may have misjudged the size of the boxes and that each ball goes into one box

Comment: That is, letting $[10]=\{1,2,3,4,\dots,10\}$ you have $10\times 9$ is the size of the set $\{(a,b)~:~a\in [10],~b\in[10],~a\neq b\}=\{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),\dots,(10,8),(10,9)\}$ while $2^{10}$ is the size of $\{(A,B)~:~A\subseteq [10],~B\subseteq [10],~A\cup B=[10],~A\cap B=\emptyset\}=\{(\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\},\emptyset),\dots,(\{1,3,5,7,9\},\{2,4,6,8,10\}),\dots\}$

Comment: You raise an interesting *hidden* question: Q1: why did you make a mistake and Q2: how can you prevent future mistakes?  These are very complex questions.  For Q1: In Combinatorics problems, intuition is very important.  So you have to find some way of developing your intuition.  The only way that I know of is by attacking more and more Combinatorics problems.  ...see next comment

Comment: For Q2: I advise **sanity-checking** which comes in two forms: (a) If you think that you have the correct formula for a problem, choose a smaller example, where you can manually enumerate the answer.  Then check if the formula gives the correct answer in the example with smaller numbers.  (b) Use computer programming, with your programming language of choice (e.g. Java, C, python, ...) and have the computer manually enumerate the right answer.  Then check this answer against the answer given by whatever formula you came up with.